# Difference between "Your father angry at me" and "Your father angry to me"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

A few days ago I watched an Indonesian movie which had English subtitles. And I was confused when I saw the sentences:

> Your father angry at me

It's that different from this sentence? Or is something wrong?

> Your father angry to me

Comment: Actually, the subtitle lacks a linking verb (i.e., "... father is angry...").

Comment: It is an incomplete translation. Without the original text (and someone to translate it) it is not possible to know what the correct sentence should be.

Comment: Incidentally, "***A*** few days ago ***I watched*** an Indonesian movie ***that had*** English subtitle***s***, and I ***was*** confused when I ***saw the sentence*** ... "Is that different than this sentence?" ... "Or ***is*** something wrong?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be angry **with** someone, or angry **at** someone, but you can't be angry *to* someone.

Source: [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/angry)